# How to set the statusBar color in an internal screen?

Tags: swift, colors, statusbar

I have this MainScreen, which has its MainScreenViewController and in that viewController I can set the statusBar color. Fine so far. But there are also two internal screens whose statusBar colors are being set the same (white), when in fact they need to be black so they don't disappear into the background. How can I do that? Should I create ViewControllers for them? I'm just starting out with coding, so I don't know if there's another approach here, so I've been looking for a way to set the status bar color only on this screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).